# How to Format Excel Columns From Specific Row to Down

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Starting From B5, C5, D5, .... I have an excel file which looks like below:

[image]

Please be advised that I have some titles and heading text on first 3 rows so I need to have Macro to set type of each columns from row 5 to end based on the title of the rows( titles are just for mentioning the required type) can you please let me know how I can do this in Excel VBA?

Thanks

Comment: how would we know which row the header has?

Comment: Hi Siddharth, sorry i didn't get what you mean?

Comment: Will it always be 5? I mean from where you want to start formatting?

Comment: check the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I am showing an example for `Column B`. Do it for the rest.

**Logic**:

1. Find Last Row in a Column. See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)
2. Construct your range
3. Format the range as required.

**Code**:

```
Private Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, Header As Long

    Header = 5 '<~~ Start row for formatting

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("B" & Header & ":B" & LastRow)
            '
            '~~> Change format here
            '
             '~~> Number with 5 decimal places.
            .NumberFormat = "0.00000"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP FROM COMMENTS**

> Thanks but this just formatting the B5 cell, can you please let me know how i can do the rest of rows from 5 to like 1000 –  Behseini 11 secs ago

Oh so if there are no values after row 5 and you want to hardcode the last row then use this code

```
Private Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, Header As Long

    Header = 5     '<~~ Start row for formatting
    LastRow = 1000 '<~~ Last Row

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        With .Range("B" & Header & ":B" & LastRow)
            '
            '~~> Change format here
            '
            '~~> Number with 5 decimal places.
            .NumberFormat = "0.00000"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth but how to change the format? i mean how can I specfiy the column to be Number with 5 Decimal place for example?

Comment: @Behseini: I have updated the code. Refresh the page to see the updated reply.

Comment: Thanks but this just formatting the B5 cell, can you please let me know how i can do the rest of rows from 5 to like 1000